# Move to next text match in WPF ComboBox with IsEditable="True"

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have an editable ComboBox with `ItemsSource="{Binding PeopleList}"` binding, each object in PeopleList has the DescribePerson property, when I starting writing out the first letters in the ComboBox, I saw first item with matched text, but the problem is that the PeopleList has several elements matching the entered text. When I opening the combobox, I want to see only matching elements instead of all nearby first matched element, how I can do that? Is there a way to move through matching items using hotkeys?

Comment: What do you mean by _all nearby first matched element_?

Comment: Are you wanting to filter ComboBox drop-down based on the text you've typed into it?

Comment: Search and filter data are two different things. It sounds like you want to filter the data (only show relevant matches).

Comment: Sorry for the wording. Task: Hide all non-matching items from editable ComboBox when typing.

Answer (score 0):

Search and filter data are two different things. It sounds like you want to filter the data (only show relevant matches) based on the user's search predicate.

Collection filtering is done by using the proper `ICollectionView` that is used for the `ItemsSource`. Unless the `ICollectionView` was explicitly created, the used view is the default view.
The default `IcollectionView` can be obtained by calling the static `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` framework method.
To obtain the current search input, simply reference the `ComboBox.Text` property (for example via data binding):

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding DataItems, Mode=OneTime}"
          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
          IsEditable="True"
          Text="{Binding SearchTextValue, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<string> DataItems { get; }

  private string searchTextValue;
  public string SearchTextValue
  {
    get => this.searchtextValue;;
    set
    {
      this.searchTextValue = value;
      OnSearchTextValueChanged();
    }
  }

  private static void OnSearchTextValueChanged()
  {
    ICollectionView dataItemsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.DataItems);

    // Apply the filter
    dataItemsView.Filter = item => (item as string).Contains(this.SearchTextValue, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
  }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

    this.DataItems = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
      "DataItem #1",
      "DataItem #2",
      "Text #1",
      "Text #2",
    };
  }
}
```